# Unable to execute Typescript, NodeJS, and Sequelize due to a Model Error

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am attempting to run sequelize on NodeJS. I am writing the code in Typescript
The versions of software I am using is as follows:

> nodejs - 14.16.0  sequelize - 6.5.1 typescript - 4.2.3

Typescript builds correctly but when running the node command against the compiled index.js file, I get the following error:

```
import { DataTypes, Model, Sequelize, TableHints } from 'sequelize';
                    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'Model' not found. The requested module 'sequelize' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'sequelize';
const { DataTypes, Model, Sequelize, TableHints } = pkg;
```

The code is a simple index.ts

```
import { DataTypes, Model, Optional, Sequelize, TableHints } from 'sequelize';

let server = "server";
let database = "db";
let user_name = "user";
let password = "password";

let app_name = "api";

let _mssql_service = new Sequelize(database, user_name, password, {
  dialect: "mssql",
  isolationLevel: TableHints.READUNCOMMITTED,
  host: server,
  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      appName: app_name,
    },
  },
});

// These are all the attributes in the User model
export interface TrackingAttributes {
  id: number;
  column1: string;
   ...
}

interface TrackingCreationAttributes
  extends Optional<TrackingAttributes, "id"> {}

export class TrackingModel
  extends Model<TrackingAttributes, TrackingCreationAttributes>
  implements TrackingAttributes {
  public id!: number; // Note that the `null assertion` `!` is required in strict mode.
  public column1!: string;
  ...
}

async function test() {
  try {
   TrackingModel.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        column1: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
          allowNull: true
        },
      },
      {
        tableName: "table1",
        schema: "schema1",
        sequelize: _mssql_service, // passing the `sequelize` instance is required
      }
    );
    let val = await TrackingModel.findOne({ where: { id: 24 } });
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
    console.log(val);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
  } finally {
    _mssql_service.close();
  }
}
test();
```

I have the following types installed and included in package.json:

> "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
> "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.9",
> "@types/validator": "^13.1.3"

I have the following tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "bin",
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["tests", "dist", "node_modules", "lib", "bin"]
}
```

I have the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "console-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^6.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.3"
  }
}
```

I am stumped on why I am getting this error but any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `@types/*` packages match the major version of the package they provide types for. In this case you have `sequelize` v6 but `@types/sequelize` v4 so they don't match.

I had a look at the sequelize repo and found that they provide their own types since v5, so you should uninstall `@types/sequelize` as those are not needed and are the cause of your issue.

See here for the info I found - https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html

Edit: Additional info in issues with `tsconfig.json`/`package.json` after OP updated their post to include it.

First of all, you need to include `typescript` in your dependencies list. You can simply run `npm i typescript` (or use a specific version if you need to).

Then, the issue with your `tsconfig.json` is that you have set the `module` compiler option to `esnext` but Node does not support this out of the box (Node *does* has experimental support for this via the `--experimental-modules` flag, but I'm ignoring this for now). You should set this to `commonjs` instead.

Working `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "bin",
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["tests", "dist", "node_modules", "lib", "bin"]
}
```

With this I was able to compile and run the code, although I now get a separate error which is `Error: Please install tedious package manually` from sequelize - but this is just a dependency issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it did not work. I ran the npm uninstall command against that type, then retranspiled with tsc and then ran the node command with the same error, that I reported. I also tried deleting the node_modules folder and then tsc..node commands. Same result

Comment: I tried it myself with the exact code you posted and a basic tsconfig.json and it works fine for me. Could you please post your tsconfig.json and maybe your package.json too?

Comment: I added the information you requested. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Can you try removing the `typeRoots` property from your `tsconfig.json`? I think that might be the issue. If not, I'll test it out with your exact files when I get a chance

Comment: @thxmike I've updated my answer with some additional help which should resolve your issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7133623/cdimitroulas: I commented this line and now it will not transpile. Error Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions

  tsconfig.json:10:15
    10     "types": ["node"],
                     ~~~~~~
    File is entry point of type library specified her

Comment: See my updated answer above - I tested it out with your files and found the problem to be 1. that you didn't have `typescript` in your dependencies, 2. that you had the wrong `module` property in your tsconfig.json

Comment: Thanks for the continued perseverance. Unfortunately I am still seeing the same error with the changes you recommended. I have even deleted the node modules and bin folders and reran the npm install and tsc commands. In regards to the tsconfig.json/commonjs change I get a new error "ReferenceError: exports is not defined". I set it to es2020 and got the Model not found error as described above

Comment: I also got "ReferenceError: exports is not defined" when I first tried, but somehow I fixed it - I thought it was the "module" option but it must have been something else then hmm.